# Как добавить столбец в таблицу в Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу улучшить html-страницу с помощью Greasemonkey и javascript.

Моя цель: добавить дополнительную ячейку после последней ячейки в каждой строке таблицы.

```
<table class="villages borderGap">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="name">Деревня:</th>
          <th class="oases">Оазисы</th>
          <th class="inhabitants"><i class="population_medium"></i></th>
          <th class="coordinates">Координаты</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td class="name"><a href="/karte.php?d=80401">Natars</a></td>
          <td class="oases"><div></div></td>
          <td class="inhabitants">854</td>
          <td class="coordinates">
              <a class="" href="/karte.php?x=0&amp;y=0">&#x202D;
              <span class="coordinates coordinatesWrapper coordinatesAligned coordinatesltr">
                  <span class="coordinateX">(&#x202D;0&#x202C;</span>
                  <span class="coordinatePipe">|</span>
                  <span class="coordinateY">&#x202D;0&#x202C;)</span>
              </span>&#x202C;
              </a>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

хочу добавить столбец

```
<table class="villages borderGap">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="name">Деревня:</th>
          <th class="oases">Оазисы</th>
          <th class="inhabitants"><i class="population_medium"></i></th>
          <th class="coordinates">Координаты</th>
          <th class="delta">delta</th><!-- add JavaScript -->
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td class="name"><a href="/karte.php?d=80401">Natars</a></td>
          <td class="oases"><div></div></td>
          <td class="inhabitants">854</td>
          <td class="coordinates">
              <a class="" href="/karte.php?x=0&amp;y=0">&#x202D;
              <span class="coordinates coordinatesWrapper coordinatesAligned coordinatesltr">
                  <span class="coordinateX">(&#x202D;0&#x202C;</span>
                  <span class="coordinatePipe">|</span>
                  <span class="coordinateY">&#x202D;0&#x202C;)</span>
              </span>&#x202C;
              </a>
          </td>
          <td class="delta">delta</td><!--add JavaScript -->
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Выбрать необходимые элементы можно с [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Создать новые с [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). Вставить с [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Всё вместе должно выглядеть примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14964510/3129992).